# The application.js file is being ignored by webpacker compilation in rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6, webpacker

In a `rails 6` application upgraded from `rails 5` I have the following pack files

```
#app/javascript/packs/application.js
import "core-js/stable";
import "regenerator-runtime/runtime";
require("trix")
require("@rails/actiontext")
```

and

```
#app/javascript/packs/application.scss
@import '../stylesheets/datatables.scss';
```

The `webpack-dev-server` server compiles successfully, but the javascript included in the `application.js` file is not running. Indeed if I change `require("trix")` to `require("no_such_file")` it does not cause a compilation error, so my `application.js` is being completely ignored.  How do I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is related to the this `webpacker` [issue](https://github.com/rails/webpacker/issues/1214) (or feature).  It seems that if you have another file called `application` in the packs directory, e.g. `application.scss`, then webpacker overwrites the output of application.js.  Basically I needed to move `application.scss` out of the packs directory and import it in the `application.js` file. This [post](https://github.com/rails/webpacker/issues/1214#issuecomment-386243321) in the issue report explains this in more detail.